# Object size limitations in Room

Tags: android, database, object, null, size

This is a general question on how the Room persistence library operates in Android.
I encountered a possible bug/feature of Room where if I tried to insert a POJO with too much data in it into a Room Object DAO, then querying the object later on, either by id or by a specific field, gives a null result.

Room provides absolutely no failure/error logs in this case, and it took me a while to find out that if I split the large object into two objects with half the data, then I was able to query both objects later on (I had noticed that another POJO in my Db with 3500 String subobjects was queried correctly, but the abovementioned oversized object has 6500 String subobjects).

To be specific, the following is the problematic object's structure, where for simplicity I excluded the getters/setters:

```
@Entity(tableName = KanjiComponent.TABLE_NAME)
public class KanjiComponent {

    public KanjiComponent() {}

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(index = true, name = COLUMN_ID)
    public long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_COMPONENT_STRUCTURE)
    private String structure;

    @TypeConverters({MyAppDbTypeConverters.class})
    private List<KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent> associatedComponents;

    public static class AssociatedComponent {
        private String component;
        private String associatedComponents;
    }
}
```

The field "component" in KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent is a one-character String, but the field "associatedComponents" in KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent can be anything from a short String to a very long String of ";" delimited characters.

List of KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent has size 6500 in my problematic object, and objects with a List size of up to about 3500 did not meet any problems.
So I created two objects with KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent list sizes of 3000 and 3500, and everything works fine now.

All my inserts/requests are done on background threads, and requesting the full database (`List<KanjiComponent> list = myDatabase.getInstance().getAllKanjiComponents()`) also yields a result with size 0 even though there are now 19 valid KanjiComponent objects (ie. with up to 3500 subobjects each) in the database.

Requesting other object databases in the same app and in the same background thread works fine. Querying for the full abovementioned database yields a size of 0, but another POJO database with 85000 small-sized objects can be requested fully, giving a list size of 85000. So there is no problem with Room itself.

I'm guessing that there are inherent object size limitations on POJOs either in Android or in Room, but I haven't been able to find information on this. I'm also unsure how to measure the size of my large POJOs to find the value of that problematic size threshold.

Has anyone come across this issue?
Is there a better way to solve it other than manually splitting oversized objects before inserting them into Room?
What are the object size and/or subobject count limitations in Room/Android?

Thanks

Comment: What is a "subobject"? Ignoring Room and Java for a moment, is a "subobject" a row in a table, a column in a table, or something else?

Comment: Edited my question to make things more specific :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that there are inherent object size limitations on POJOs either in Android or in Room, but I haven't been able to find information on this

Any query whose result set is over 1MB is going to be prone to problems. While in principle it should work, in practice I aim would avoid it.

> List of KanjiComponent.AssociatedComponent has size 6500 in my problematic object

So, to be clear:

- You have a list of 6,500+ objects
- Each one of those objects can have a string of "a very long String of ";" delimited characters"
- You are using a `TypeConverters` to cram all of that into a single column

If so, I would expect this to be very unreliable, due to `OutOfMemoryErrors`.

> Is there a better way to solve it other than manually splitting oversized objects before inserting them into Room?

Change the database design to avoid having a massive column. Have two tables with corresponding Room entities. `AssociatedComponent` gets its own table/entity, with a 1:N relationship between `KanjiComponent` and `AssociatedComponent`. Consider using the Paging library to only load subsets into memory as needed (e.g., for scrolling lists).

Comment: Well, since the set of Kanji characters doesn't really grow that much over time and I'm currently not implementing a very dynamic UI, for now I guess splitting the object is a 'good enough' approach for standard phone capabilities (no delays/out of memory on my 2016 phone), as long as the resulting object is processed fast in a separate thread and not kept in memory for too long. Even so, I accept your suggestion and will think of how to rework the database in the future.

Comment: @BarLr: Your amount of free heap space will vary widely, based on device, OS version, and what all has been done in your process prior to the database query.